# How to zero the milisecond time in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table of times I've entered in excel. 
The calculations added some fraction of times to my field so
0:13:13 is actually 0:13:13:1282

How can I get the exact time without the milliseconds part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your calculations in an `MROUND` function to round to the nearest second, e.g.

`=MROUND(your_calc,"0:00:01")`

or you could round **down** with `FLOOR` function in a similar way

`=FLOOR(your_calc,"0:00:01")`

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to the fact that Excel stores timestamps as “OLE Automation dates”.

From the .NET [`DateTime.ToOADate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation:

> An OLE Automation date is implemented as a floating-point number whose integral component is the number of days before or after midnight, 30 December 1899, and whose fractional component represents the time on that day divided by 24. For example, midnight, 31 December 1899 is represented by 1.0; 6 A.M., 1 January 1900 is represented by 2.25; midnight, 29 December 1899 is represented by -1.0; and 6 A.M., 29 December 1899 is represented by -1.25.
>
> The base OLE Automation Date is midnight, 30 December 1899. The minimum OLE Automation date is midnight, 1 January 0100. The maximum OLE Automation Date is the same as `DateTime.MaxValue`, the last moment of 31 December 9999.

Floating-point numbers as processed in PCs are subject to more or less severe rounding errors, with some worst-case fractions.

One day has `24 * 60 * 60 = 86400` seconds in total.

```
(13 * 60 + 13) / 86400 = 0,00917824074074

(13 * 60 + 13 + 0,1282) / 86400 = 0,00917972453704
```

As you can see, the numbers are very similar and only differ starting from the 6th decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

To simply discard the milliseconds part, in **B1** enter:

```
=TIMEVALUE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-5))
```

and apply a Time format to **B1**

[image]